# Android table with cursor adapter

Tags: android, gridview, cursor, tableview

I'm trying to create `tableview` (like spreadsheet in Excel). The table need to read the data from `cursor` (example 30k records) and to work with recycling of views like `ListView` and `GridView`. The table must be fast and to have `re-sizable` columns (example I like to have 4 columns , each with differed size).

What I have done :

1. `GridView` with custom Cursor adapter

   - looks like table with header row (names for the columns)
   - table is fast, reading form cursor and recycling view
   - column re-sizing is not possible because on GridView draws all columns with same size
2. Each column is `ListView` and they have synced scrolling listener

   - looks like table
   - on fling scrolling if you touch some list it will stop and other lists will continue to   scroll
   - to dirty solution
3. `TableLayout` with adapter

   - is reading form adapter
   - no recycling views, and with big number of records memory exception is thrown
4. Custom `GridView`

   - Custom TableView which extends AbsListView , and I'm not able to use fields   from AbsListView because they are package protected.

I think the best View will be TableLayout/View with adapter. 
Pls help me to find the best solution for this kind of View.

p.s. maybe Roman Guy can help and code TableView for the next android version :)

Answer (score 0):

If your tableview doesn't have to be scrolled horizontally, then you could go with a `ListView` and a custom view for row. Such a row would be a `LinearLayout` (with horizontal orientation) with as many `TextView`s as columns you need, each one of them with a `weight` attribute to make their widths appropriate.

If it has to be scrolled horizontally then the only way I see it is to implement your own container based on `AdapterView`.

Comment: Thx rwozniak, I did it with listview today. And it's working with horizontal scroll.

Comment: I got custom made HorisontalScroll with
`@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
onTouchEvent(ev);
return false;
}`
I haven't tested it very well, but for now it looks fine.